# Create account via recurly js v3

Tags: javascript, recurly

So with recurly js v2, the account can be created with the js library. But in recurly js v3, how can we create an account via js (not through other languages like python in the backend) instead of only getting the token?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recurly.js v3 is fundamentally different from v2 in this way.

An account can now only be created using our API directly or through a client library.

There are a few advantages to this. First is that the API is much more powerful, and allows you much greater control of your customer flow. Previously in Recurly.js v2, a request signature had to be generated before loading the page, which usually required the use of a Recurly client library anyway. With Recurly.js v3, usage of the client library moves from before building the payment form (for building signatures) to after submission (for basic API usage).